How dataset.repeat() works with model.fit()?
I have a dataset of 1061 samples, and I am using the following:
epochs = 50 

batch_size=20

dataset = dataset.repeat(epochs).batch(batch_size)

Now if I use :
model.fit(dataset , epochs = epochs , batch_size = batch_size)

What will be the number of samples that will be input to the model in one epoch of training ? Is it 1061 ? Or 1061 * 50 = 53050 samples ?
I searched for how does the dataset.repeat() works , but I am still confused about how it works with model.fit() specifically.

You understand that correctly! when you call dataset.repeat(epochs), you will create a dataset that repeats your original samples 50 times (epoch = 50). Meaning This dataset will contain 1061 * 50 = 53050 samples.
And for each epochs, 1061 samples will be processed.
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers, models

# Create a sample dataset
num_samples = 1061
num_features = 10
X = np.random.rand(num_samples, num_features).astype(np.float32)
y = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(num_samples,)).astype(np.float32)

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X, y))
epochs = 50
batch_size = 20

# Repeat
dataset = dataset.repeat(epochs).batch(batch_size)

model = models.Sequential([
    layers.Dense(32, activation='relu', input_shape=(num_features,)),
    layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Counting samples
class SampleCountCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        samples_processed = (epoch + 1) * num_samples
        print(f"Epoch {epoch + 1}: {samples_processed} samples processed")

# Model fitting
model.fit(dataset, epochs=epochs, steps_per_epoch=num_samples // batch_size, callbacks=[SampleCountCallback()])




Thanks. I think samples_processed should be  (epoch + 1) * batch_size * steps_per_epoch instead , Am I correct ? I am just trying to define the callback in a way irrespective of the information we already know about (num_samples ), but instead with parameters we give to the model.fit()
